Formalizing the construction of a Cantor scheme
I'm asking this question here since a similar question asked on math.stackexchange didn't receive an answer.
I'm trying to understand the proof of the following theorem:
Theorem (Brouwer): The Cantor space $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is the unique, up to homeomorphism, perfect nonempty, compact metrizable, zero-dimensional space.
The proofs I saw start constructing a function $\varphi :\{0,1\}^{<\mathbb{N}}\to \mathcal{P}(X)$ (with $X$ being an arbitrary space with those properties) having the following properties:

$\varphi (\emptyset)=X$
$\varphi (s)$ is clopen and nonempty for all $s\in \{0,1\}^{<\mathbb{N}}$
$\overline{\varphi (s{}^\frown i)}\subseteq \varphi (s)$ for any $s\in \{0,1\}^{<\mathbb{N}}$ and $i\in \{0,1\}$
$\varphi (s{}^\frown 0)\cap \varphi (s{}^\frown 1)=\emptyset$ for all $s\in \{0,1\}^{<\mathbb{N}}$
$\varphi (s)=\varphi (s{}^\frown 0)\cup\varphi (s{}^\frown 1)$ for all $s\in \{0,1\}^{<\mathbb{N}}$
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{diam}(\varphi (x|n))=0$ for all $x\in \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$.

(The previous notations are those commonly used to study set theoretic trees.)
According to the book "Classical Descriptive Set Theory" written by Alexander S. Kechris (see pg 35), the function can the constructed inductively. I'll quote what the book says:

Split $X$ into $X=X_1\cup\dotsb\cup X_n$, where $X_i\cap
 X_j=\emptyset $ if $i\neq j$ and $X_i$ is clopen of diameter $<1/2$.
Let $\varphi (0^i{}^\frown 1)=X_{i+1}$ if $0\leq i<n-1$, $\varphi(0^{n-1})=X_n$, and $\varphi (0^i)=X_{i+1}\cup \dotsb\cup X_n$, for
$0\leq i<n-1$ (here $a^j=aa\dotsm a$ ($j$ times)). Now repeat this
process within each $X_i$, using sets of diameter $<1/3$, and so on by
induction.

I understand each step of the construction of $\varphi (s)$, but I'd like to know how to make this construction rigorous. So my question is, how can I make that construction mathematical rigorous?
I tried to use the Recursion Theorem (see Theorem 23.1 of "Classical Set Theory: Theory of Sets and Classes" by Banakh), but I didn't make any progress.
One problem I'm facing is that each step of that construction requires the definition of $\varphi (s)$ for $s\in \{0,1\}^{<\mathbb{N}}$ with different heights, so I don't know how to use Recursion Theorem to make this construction rigorous.

EDIT:
I'll write two theorems I found in the book "Notes on Set Theory" (by Yiannis Moschovakis) that might help someone to find a way to define rigorously the function $\varphi :\{0,1\}^{<\mathbb{N}}\to \mathcal{P}(X)$.
String Recursion Theorem: For any two sets $A,E$, each $a\in E$, and each function $h:E\times A\to E$, there is exactly one function $f:A^{<\mathbb{N}}\to E$ which satisfies the identities: $f(\emptyset )=a$ and $f(s{}^\frown a)=h(f(s),a)$ for any $s\in A^{<\mathbb{N}}$ and $a\in A$.
String Recursion Theorem with Parameters: For any three sets $A,E,Y$, each $a\in E$ and any functions $g:Y\to E$ and $h:E\times A\times Y\to E$, there exists exactly one function $f:A^{<\mathbb{N}}\times Y\to E$ which satisfies the identities: $f(\emptyset ,y)=g(y)$ and $f(s{}^\frown a,y)=h(f(s,y),a,y)$ for any $y\in Y$, $s\in A^{<\mathbb{N}}$ and $a\in A$.
My problem in this moment is to define appropriate sets $E$ and $Y$ in order to use one of the previous theorems to obtain the function $\varphi$.

Aren't you just choosing the later spaces $X_{s{}^\frown i}$ by the axiom of choice? (Actually, DC suffices.) That is, you fix by DC a way of choosing, and then you use those choices to define the recursion. What is the specific issue that you find troublesome?

@JoelDavidHamkins I don’t you meant by saying “ you fix by DC a way of choosing, and then you use those choices to define the recursion”. Could you please write an answer explaining it?

You can assume that there is a function that chooses a suitable next space, given the previous space. This is exactly the kind of thing that the axiom of choice and even DC gives you. Then, you are defining the recursion using that function. Was this the confusing point?

To use the Recursion Theorem I need to define a function of the form $F:Y\times\mathbf{V}\to\mathbf{V}$ with $Y$ being a set. I also need a set-like well-founded relation $R$ such $\text{dom}[R]\subseteq Y$. My problem is that I don't how to define $Y$ and $R$ (maybe $R=\big{(s,t)\in ({0,1}^{<\mathbb{N}})^2:s\subseteq t\big}$) in order to obtain $\varphi$ satisfying those properties. One problem is that for each step of the construction I don't exactly how many disjoint clopen sets are necessary to cover $\varphi (s)$.

Yes, the order on finite binary sequences by extending them is clearly well-founded, and therefore by the recursion theorem we can define things by recursion on finite binary sequences, which is what you are doing. The issue about how many clopen sets etc. is basically not important, as long as you can bound the set of possible things you would want, which is clearly true here, then you are just using the axiom of choice to pick from every partial solution a next suitable element. So by the recursion theorem, you've got a full solution with $X_s$ defined for every $s$.

Is there a difference between ${0, 1}^{\mathbb N}$, which you use first, and ${0, 1}^{< \mathbb N}$, which you use later?

@LSpice Yes, the set ${0,1}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to{0,1}$. The ${0,1}^{<\mathbb{N}}$ is the set of all finite binary sequences.

I'm not sure how this will affect the bounty you have placed, however, and so perhaps the moderators should get involved. I have flagged for their attention. Not sure what is best...

The formalization of the Cantor scheme can look as follows.
Given a metric space $(X,d)$, denote by $\mathcal T$ the family of nonempty open sets in $X$. Using the Axiom of Choice, choose any function $S:\mathcal T\times\{0,1\}\times\omega\to\mathcal T$ assigning to every triple $(U,i,n)$ a set $S(U,i,n)\in\mathcal T$ such that $S(U,i,n)\subseteq U$, $\overline{S(U,0,n)}\cap \overline{S(U,1,n)}=\varnothing$ and $diam(S(U,i,k))\le 2^{-n}$.
If $X$ is second-countable, then the function $S$ can be constructed without AC (instead of $\mathcal T$ take a countable base for $X$ with a fixed bijection to $\omega$ and then put $S(U,i,n)$ to be the suitable basic set with the smallest number).
Let $2^{<\omega}=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}2^n$ be the binary tree with the standard partial order $\le$. For every $s\in 2^{<\omega}$, let ${\downarrow}s=\{t\in 2^{<\omega}:t<s\}$.
Define a function $F:2^{<\omega}\times \mathbf V\to\mathbf V$ assigning to every pair $(s,v)\in 2^{<\omega}\times \mathbf V$ the set $X$ if $s\in 2^0$ or $v$ is not a function with domain ${\downarrow}s$ and range $\mathcal T$. If $s\notin 2^0$ and $v$ is a function with domain ${\downarrow}s$ and range $\mathcal T$, then put $F(s,v)=S(v(s(n-1)),s(n),n)$, where $n$ is the largest number in $dom(s)\in \omega\setminus\{0\}$.
Applying the Recursion Theorem to the function $F$, we obtain a function $G:2^{<\omega}\to \mathbf V$ such that $G(s)=F(s,G{\restriction}_{{\downarrow}s})$ for every $s\in 2^{<\omega}$.
By induction we can show that $G(s)\in\mathcal T$ for every $s$ and $G(s\hat{\,}0)$, $G(s\hat{\,}1)$ are two open subsets of diameter$<2^{-n}$ in  $G(s)$ with disjoint closures. So, $(G(s))_{s\in 2^{<\omega}}$ is the required Cantor schema.

Thank you very much!

@rfloc I have read from your posts that you are going to learn some theorem provers line Lean or Coq. Have you any experience in that direction? Is it difficult for a mathematician with a classical education?

I stopped this project. If you want to learn a theorem prover, I recommend learning Lean 4, which is not difficult to learn. Terrence Tao wrote two great blog posts about using Lean 4 to prove theorems, as you can see in this link. To learn Lean 4, you just need to read the tutorials that are available on Lean's official website.

Thanks for the advize and link to Tao's blog. Surely, I will read it because this topic interests me quite a lot (as a future of math).

It seems to me that you are worried about the formalism surrounding the recursion theorem, which is the fundamental theorem asserting that definitions by recursion on a well-founded relation are successful. The recursion theorem states that for any way of specifying how a partial solution should continue, there is a fully defined solution that at each step obeys that rule. One can prove this in ZF by proving that all partial solutions agree so far as they go (since there can be no least point of disagreement) and any given strictly partial solution can be extended further (since we can just apply the rule one more step); consequently, the union of all partial solutions will be the desired full solution.
In your case, you are defining the sets $X_s$ for finite binary sequences $s\in 2^{<\omega}$. This is certainly a well-founded relation (ordered by extension), since any nonempty set of finite binary sequences will have one of minimal length, and this will be minimal in the set. And therefore, this relation will support definitions by recursion on the finite binary sequences $s$.
One can formalize your construction in ZFC (but actually ZF+DC would suffice, with a weaker choice principle — let us set this aside). Namely, regardless of the previous $X_s$, your argument provides a criterion of what would constitute suitable $X_{s{}^\frown 0}$ and $X_{s{}^\frown 1}$, without necessarily picking unique instances yet. Rather, the point is that the space of all possible suitable answers to this question exist inside the set of subsets of $X$.
But we may simply use a choice function on the entire space of possibilities, which will provide for each possible space $X_s$ particular definite spaces $X_{s0}$ and $X_{s1}$. It is this definition to which we are applying the recursion theorem. And that theorem says that there is a full solution, a map $s\mapsto X_s$ that obeys the recursive definition at each step $s$.
I hope this helps, but I worry that I may have fundamentally misunderstood the issue that troubles you.

Thank you very much for your answer! I'll write what I'm trying to do: denote by $\mathbf{C}$ the set of all nonempty clopen subsets of $X$. For each $U\in\mathbf{C}$ associate a list $X_{U,1},\cdots,X_{U,n(U)}\in\mathbf{C}$ of disjoint sets such that $U=\cup_{i=1}^{n(U)}X_{U,i}$. I believe that my "recursion function" $F$ must have the form $F:2^{<\mathbb{N}}\times\mathbf{V}\to\mathbf{C}$. I also believe that in order to define recursively $\varphi$ using $F$, I must firstly define $F(s,U)$ for any $s\in2^{<\mathbb{N}}$ and $U\in\mathbf{C}$. But I don't know how to make this definition.
